# Azure blob storage gives authentication error when connecting using sas (Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect to an azure blob storage (listing an containers to check if it works), however when I connect I get an authentication error. Here is my code

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

top_level_container_name = "top_container"
sas_url ="https://secret.blob.core.windows.net/table?sv=2020-10-02&st=2022-05-16T10%3A11%3A57Z&se=2022-05-28T21%3A59%3A00Z&sr=c&sp=rl&sig=secret"
service=BlockBlobService(account_name="thi" ,sas_token=sas_url)

containers = service.list_containers() 
for c in containers: 
     print(c.name)
```

Which when run gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thijser\codes\python\listblobs.py", line 11, in <module>
    containers = service.list_containers()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 514, in list_containers
    resp = self._list_containers(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 558, in _list_containers
    return self._perform_request(request, _convert_xml_to_containers, operation_context=_context)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 280, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 248, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 235, in _perform_request
    _http_error_handler(HTTPError(response.status, response.message, response.headers, response.body))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\_error.py", line 114, in _http_error_handler
    raise AzureHttpError(message, http_error.status)
azure.common.AzureHttpError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:2bc0650b-d01e-0050-511b-69cc86000000
Time:2022-05-16T11:54:26.0333719Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour: Start [Mon, 16 May 2022 10:11:57 GMT] - Expiry [Sat, 28 May 2022 21:59:00 GMT]</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>
```

I am able to use the same sas link to see the files in the azure storage explorer. I have the 1.5.0 version of the azure blob storage freshly installed via pip.

Anybody know how to get rid of the error? The sas token wasn't generated by me and should actually last a whole week. I suspect it might somehow involve my password (given that changing the account_name into something that's invalid changes the error) but I can't find how to properly add that. I tried   `service=BlockBlobService(account_name="thi", account_key = "my secret password", sas_token=sas_url)` but that just changes the error into `The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'c5w+tYbWVvibQ1NGFq0sHDwfvMS4wP0nO0d/iv5KuFo=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET`

Edit:

So I figured out I have a service SAS link and not a SAS account. So that slightly changes my question into how to list everything contained in a service sas url? For this I already tried a couple of online tutorials but they keep running into the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'ContainerClient' from 'azure.storage.blob'`. Does anyone know how to fix that/list all files in such a link?

Last edit: solved it. I had to uninstall all azure related packages and install the azure-cli package. followed by the azure-storage-blob package.

Comment: Any clarifying questions are of course also welcome, I'm open to any and all comments, suggestions and questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) to perform an operation that requires an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas). List blob containers operation requires an Account SAS because you are performing an operation at account level.

To fix this error, you will need an Account SAS with at least following attributes:

- **Signed Services**: Blob
- **Signed Resource Types**: Service (to list blob containers) and Container (to list blobs inside a container)
- **Signed Permission**: List (for list operations)

Comment: Thanks you, so that makes me next question if it would it be possible to use a service sas to somehow list all files and their sizes in a given blob storage?

Comment: `it would it be possible to use a service sas to somehow list all files and their sizes in a given blob storage` - If by blob storage you mean the whole account, then the answer is no. Please note that a Service SAS is scoped to a single blob container so that SAS token can only be used for the blob container for which it was generated. You can use an Account SAS to list blobs in a blob container. When you use an Account SAS, you can list blobs in any blob container in that storage account.

Comment: With Account SAS, the approach would be to first list all blob containers in a storage account and then list blobs in each of those blob containers.

Comment: Thank you that at least helps me figure out where I should be looking. (hopefully the last question): you say I cannot list everything in the account but is there a way to list everything in the service SAS? I have found a bunch of tutorials like this here: https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.12.0/azure.storage.blob.html but they all seem to result in  the error ImportError: cannot import name 'BlobClient' from 'azure.storage.blob' (or some other missing import)

Comment: `you say I cannot list everything in the account but is there a way to list everything in the service SAS?` - Not everything in the account but you can list everything in a blob container using Service SAS. Regarding the error, BlobClient definitely exists in `azure.storage.blob` package so you should not be getting the error. Have you installed older versions of SDK by any chance?

Comment: I have newly installed azure-storage-blob today and running `pip install azure-storage-blob` gives me the following first 3 lines: `Requirement already satisfied: azure-storage-blob in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: azure-storage-common~=1.4 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from azure-storage-blob) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: azure-common>=1.1.5 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from azure-storage-blob) (1.1.28)`

Comment: I have seen this issue in some other questions here. You should be able to find a solution for this particular problem by searching for this error. If you're not able to find it, please post a new question.

Comment: Yes, I found the solution, I deinstalled all the azure related packages and installed the azure-cli package. That worked. 

Thank you!